# Testing controller class post method when its return type is Response Entity

Tags: spring-boot, testng

The below code tests a post method using testng and mockito. I am getting  an error at line assertThat(outputInJson).isEqualTo(inputInJson). The controller class post method returns responseEntity object when an offer is created.

```
    @Test
public void testCreateOffer() throws Exception {
    Offer offer = new Offer("SE", new Date(), 10);

    MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(new ServletRequestAttributes(request));

    URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{jobTitle}")
            .buildAndExpand(offer.getJobTitle()).toUri();

    String inputInJson = this.mapToJson(ResponseEntity.created(location).build());
    Mockito.when(offerService.createOffer(Mockito.any(Offer.class))).thenReturn(offer);

    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/offers").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(inputInJson).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

    MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();

    String outputInJson = response.getContentAsString();

    assertThat(outputInJson).isEqualTo(inputInJson);

    assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.CREATED.value());

}

private String mapToJson(Object object) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
}
```

and controller class post method

```
@PostMapping("/offers")

public ResponseEntity<Object> createOffer(@Valid @RequestBody Offer offer) {
    Offer uoffer = offerService.createOffer(offer);

    URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{jobTitle}")
            .buildAndExpand(uoffer.getJobTitle()).toUri();

    return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();

}
```

Comment: It’s hard to provide a full answer without seeing some more context, but you shouldn’t be using `ResponseEntity` to create the JSON that you are POSTing. `ResponseEntity` is intended to be used when creating a response when you need control of more than just the body. It should not be used when creating a request.

Comment: I am creating a post method which is used to create an offer. If i don't use response entity the the return status will be 200 but i have created status 201 using response entity and the same has to be done while doing testing. If you want more context then i can provide you will the controller class post method which has been  include in the question now.

Comment: Your controller code is fine and should continue to use `ResponseEntity`. Your test should be updated to use the JSON representation of the Offer that the POST will create as the body of the request.

Comment: I have created mapToJson method wherein i pass the response entity generated offer. You can have a look at the code.